# Nativescript Angular code sharing project problem with Webpack

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have created a code-sharing projects with Angular 8.30 and Nativescript.

When I run `ng serve`, the app builds ok. However with `tns run android` I have problems with Webpack.

Here is the error:

```
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[1] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[2] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
    at validate (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at new CopyPlugin (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:24:30)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\webpack.config.js:302:13)
    at handleFunction (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:23:13)
    at prepareOptions (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:136:14)
    at C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:241:39
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:219:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:538:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\garma\Desktop\test--project\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const { join, relative, resolve, sep, dirname } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const { nsReplaceBootstrap } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-bootstrap");
const { nsReplaceLazyLoader } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-lazy-loader");
const { nsSupportHmrNg } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-support-hmr-ng");
const { getMainModulePath } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/utils/ast-utils");
const { getNoEmitOnErrorFromTSConfig, getCompilerOptionsFromTSConfig } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/utils/tsconfig-utils");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const { getAngularCompilerPlugin } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin");
const hashSalt = Date.now().toString();

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = env.appComponents || [];
    appComponents.push(...[
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ]);

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios" || env.platform);
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const AngularCompilerPlugin = getAngularCompilerPlugin(platform);
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file.
        appPath = "src",
        appResourcesPath = "App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        aot, // --env.aot
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot,
        production, // --env.production
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
        unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting
        verbose, // --env.verbose
        snapshotInDocker, // --env.snapshotInDocker
        skipSnapshotTools, // --env.skipSnapshotTools
        compileSnapshot // --env.compileSnapshot
    } = env;

    const useLibs = compileSnapshot;
    const isAnySourceMapEnabled = !!sourceMap || !!hiddenSourceMap;
    const externals = nsWebpack.getConvertedExternals(env.externals);
    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const tsConfigName = "tsconfig.tns.json";
    const tsConfigPath = join(__dirname, tsConfigName);
    const hasRootLevelScopedModules = nsWebpack.hasRootLevelScopedModules({ projectDir: projectRoot });
    const hasRootLevelScopedAngular = nsWebpack.hasRootLevelScopedAngular({ projectDir: projectRoot });
    let coreModulesPackageName = "tns-core-modules";
    const alias = env.alias || {};
    alias['~'] = appFullPath;

    const compilerOptions = getCompilerOptionsFromTSConfig(tsConfigPath);
    if (hasRootLevelScopedModules) {
        coreModulesPackageName = "@nativescript/core";
        alias["tns-core-modules"] = coreModulesPackageName;
        nsWebpack.processTsPathsForScopedModules({ compilerOptions });
    }

    if (hasRootLevelScopedAngular) {
        alias["nativescript-angular"] = "@nativescript/angular";
        nsWebpack.processTsPathsForScopedAngular({ compilerOptions });
    }

    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);
    const entryModule = `${nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath, platform)}.ts`;
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}`;
    const entries = env.entries || {};
    entries.bundle = entryPath;

    const areCoreModulesExternal = Array.isArray(env.externals) && env.externals.some(e => e.indexOf("tns-core-modules") > -1);
    if (platform === "ios" && !areCoreModulesExternal) {
        entries["tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules"] = "inspector_modules";
    };

    const ngCompilerTransformers = [];
    const additionalLazyModuleResources = [];
    if (aot) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceBootstrap);
    }

    if (hmr) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsSupportHmrNg);
    }

    // when "@angular/core" is external, it's not included in the bundles. In this way, it will be used
    // directly from node_modules and the Angular modules loader won't be able to resolve the lazy routes
    // fixes https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4024
    if (env.externals && env.externals.indexOf("@angular/core") > -1) {
        const appModuleRelativePath = getMainModulePath(resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), tsConfigName);
        if (appModuleRelativePath) {
            const appModuleFolderPath = dirname(resolve(appFullPath, appModuleRelativePath));
            // include the lazy loader inside app module
            ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceLazyLoader);
            // include the new lazy loader path in the allowed ones
            additionalLazyModuleResources.push(appModuleFolderPath);
        }
    }

    const ngCompilerPlugin = new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        hostReplacementPaths: nsWebpack.getResolver([platform, "tns"]),
        platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin, resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), projectRoot)),
        mainPath: join(appFullPath, entryModule),
        tsConfigPath,
        skipCodeGeneration: !aot,
        sourceMap: !!isAnySourceMapEnabled,
        additionalLazyModuleResources: additionalLazyModuleResources,
        compilerOptions: { paths: compilerOptions.paths }
    });

    let sourceMapFilename = nsWebpack.getSourceMapFilename(hiddenSourceMap, __dirname, dist);

    const itemsToClean = [`${dist}/**/*`];
    if (platform === "android") {
        itemsToClean.push(`${join(projectRoot, "platforms", "android", "app", "src", "main", "assets", "snapshots")}`);
        itemsToClean.push(`${join(projectRoot, "platforms", "android", "app", "build", "configurations", "nativescript-android-snapshot")}`);
    }

    const noEmitOnErrorFromTSConfig = getNoEmitOnErrorFromTSConfig(join(projectRoot, tsConfigName));

    nsWebpack.processAppComponents(appComponents, platform);
    const config = {
        mode: production ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: entries,
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            sourceMapFilename,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
            hashSalt
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, `node_modules/${coreModulesPackageName}`),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                `node_modules/${coreModulesPackageName}`,
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias,
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: hiddenSourceMap ? "hidden-source-map" : (sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none"),
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "single",
            noEmitOnErrors: noEmitOnErrorFromTSConfig,
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);
                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    sourceMap: isAnySourceMapEnabled,
                    terserOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                            semicolons: !isAnySourceMapEnabled
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    include: join(appFullPath, entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                angular: true,
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                                unitTesting,
                                appFullPath,
                                projectRoot,
                                ignoredFiles: nsWebpack.getUserDefinedEntries(entries, platform)
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                { test: /\.html$|\.xml$/, use: "raw-loader" },

                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/css2json-loader",
                            options: { useForImports: true }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/css2json-loader",
                            options: { useForImports: true }
                        },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                // Angular components reference css files and their imports using raw-loader
                { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/moduleid-compat-loader",
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/lazy-ngmodule-hot-loader",
                        "@ngtools/webpack",
                    ]
                },

                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                {
                    test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                    parser: { system: true },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": "global.process",
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(itemsToClean, { verbose: !!verbose }),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            new nsWebpack.GenerateNativeScriptEntryPointsPlugin("bundle"),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            ngCompilerPlugin,
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
        ],
    };

    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            angular: true,
            requireModules: [
                "reflect-metadata",
                "@angular/platform-browser",
                "@angular/core",
                "@angular/common",
                "@angular/router",
                "nativescript-angular/platform-static",
                "nativescript-angular/router",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
            snapshotInDocker,
            skipSnapshotTools,
            useLibs
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }

    return config;
};
```

How can I figure out the fix?

Comment: Solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379652/validationerror-invalid-options-object-copy-plugin-has-been-initialized-using/65579539#65579539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this issue is related to version of **"@angular-devkit/build-angular"**.

For me works!

- After generating code sharing project:

  1. Drop folders: 'hooks', 'node_modules', 'platforms'
  2. Drop files: 'package-lock.json', 'webpack.config.js'
  3. Change version of '@angular-devkit/build-angular' from current (~0.803.0) to ~0.7.0 ; Then run **npm install**
  4. Then change '@angular-devkit/build-angular' version to current one (~0.803.0). Then run **nmp install**
  5. Test: **tns run ios --bundle**

Comment: I have 0 explanation on why this worked, but it did...  Any news from the author on a fix?  It's still present in 0.901.0

Comment: I think downgrading back the environment is a bad approach, take a look the next answer which is about how to update your webpack config to be compatible the new build-angular version (0.803+)

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me and When I try to edit webpack.config.js it works for me just replace the lines

```
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
            { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
            { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
        ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

to be

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
              { from: "fonts/**", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
              { from: "**/*.{jpg,png}", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
            ]
          }, { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

and do not forget to add fonts folder if you do not have one

Comment: This supposed to be the BEST answer. The accepted answer is about downgrading the environment instead of solving the issue with the updated version.

Comment: I tried this but I still get some errors `ERROR in unable to locate 'fonts/**' at '<app_path>/src/fonts/**'` and `ERROR in unable to locate '**/*.{jpg,png}' at '<app_path>/src/**/*.{jpg,png}`

Comment: Did you have folder with name fonts in your src ? @Lukas

Comment: yes I have. I solved the problem now by creating a new Code Share Project and copying all config files to my existing Project. Then I changed the applicationId and so on in all new files. With this solution I got a working Upgrade to Angular 10. Its not the prettiest solution but it works.