# Failed "tns run android –bundle" Invalid options object

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My application runs fine when I run using `ng serve` but when i use `tns run android --bundle` or `tns run android` then it gives me following exception.

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[1] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[2] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
    at validate (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at new CopyPlugin (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:24:30)
    at module.exports (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\webpack.config.js:304:13)
    at handleFunction (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:23:13)
    at prepareOptions (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:136:14)
    at C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:241:39
    at Object.parse (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:219:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:538:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Ambiente PGE\workspace\ui\app-mobile\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

I created the project as follows:

```
ng new my-mobile
ng add @nativescript/schematics
```

I have already updated cli, npm and nativescript to the latest version

Comment: I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361748/nativescript-angular-code-sharing-project-problem-with-webpack.

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me and When I try to edit  `webpack.config.js` it works for me just replace the lines

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
            { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
            { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
        ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

to be

```
  new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                  { from: "fonts/**", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
                  { from: "**/*.{jpg,png}", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
                ]
              }, { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

and do not forget to add fonts folder if you do not have one

Comment: sorry I realized that  now and edit it thanks for your information @MohammadRafigh