# Failed "tns preview" ValidationError: Invalid options object

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

When i run "ng serve" or "npm start" the webapplication of this shared module nativescript-angular runs great. When i use "tns preview" and scan the qr code with my mobile app everyting goes from:

```
# Use NativeScript Playground app and scan the QR code above to preview the application on your device.

To scan the QR code and deploy your app on a device, you need to have the NativeScript Playground app:
    App Store (iOS): https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nativescript-playground/id1263543946?mt=8&ls=1
    Google Play (Android): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.play

Preparing project...
```

To:

```
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[1] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[2] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
    at validate (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at new CopyPlugin (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:24:30)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\webpack.config.js:304:13)
    at handleFunction (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:23:13)
    at prepareOptions (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:136:14)
    at C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:241:39
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:219:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:538:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\source\Repos\Vacerra\VacerraR-D\V-WebApp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

- i've tried "npm installe", "ng update" and the nativescript updates + schematics to get the correct versions..
- i've uninstalled the playground and preview apps en reinstalled them..
- i've tried the steps in the answer on this problem:

[Nativescript Angular code sharing project problem with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361748/nativescript-angular-code-sharing-project-problem-with-webpack)

- i've searched google and stackoverflow

So far no luck at all.. Is there anyone out there who had this problem and did find a solution

Thanks in advance for answering!

Kind regards,

R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like CopyWebpackPlugin has been updated, but your `webpack.config.js` still uses the old configuration syntax.

The updated syntax should look something along the lines of

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  patterns: [
    { from: "fonts/**", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
    { from: "**/*.{jpg,png}", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
  ]
}),
```

Make sure you have the `fonts` folder (even if empty with a `.gitignore`) as the new version of the copy plugin will throw an error if it can't find it.

Comment: Hey Igor, do we manually edit this? My current format for the CopyWebpackPlugin is like this:

            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),

Comment: If you have an error due to using the old syntax then yes, go ahead and update it manually! There's an updated version of the webpack configs under the `@nativescript/webpack` package, but it's not officially released yet.

Answer (score -1):

See [nativescript-preview](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-preview/).  You need to have the Nativescript Playground and Preview apps installed on your device.

Comment: Hi Lester Lynch,

Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned before "I've uninstalled the playground and preview apps en reinstalled them" it's just in that he won't open the preview. I tested the tutorial preview of nativescript where I don't have this problem.

Comment: Your right!, my bad!  Are all of your plugins included in the included preview dependencies?

Comment: Hi Lester, i've updated all dependencies but that didn't change much.. The actual answer is the one above. The copy plugin config did not change and the code did.. 

Thank you for your time to look at my problem and your answers trying to resolve this issue.

Kind regards