# Unable to Create Angular Native Shared Application

Tags: angular, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript-angular, tns

I am following https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/angular-cli#installation doc to create NativaScript + Angular Shared application

I did the following

`npm i -g @angular/cli`

`npm i -g @nativescript/schematics`

then from suitable folder

`ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-mobile-app --shared --sample --prefix=my --style=scss`

**Finally landing into following error**

*npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/http@~9.1.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'my-mobile-app'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-15T18_27_24_869Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.*

Can Some body help.
I tried with multiple angular version
@angular/cli V 8.x, 9.x, 10.x
@nativescript/schematic@9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears there is a problem with the published version of @nativescript/schematics.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/283

There are instructions in there on how to download the latest schematics.

After that, I ran into the following error:

```
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[1] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
 - options[2] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

Which was fixed by doing what is explained in:
[Nativescript Angular code sharing project problem with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361748/nativescript-angular-code-sharing-project-problem-with-webpack)

Which led to the project building successfully, and then

```
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Successfully transferred package.json on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred tns-java-classes.js on device emulator-5554.
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Cannot compile /data/data/org.nativescript.test/files/app/bundle.js
System.err: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
System.err: File: (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.test/files/app/bundle.js:34:144)
```

and from there I'm stuck...

I've tried disabling IVY and running with ivy as discussed https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/wiki/Updating-and-developing-for-@nativescript-angular-v9-with-Ivy-or-without and have had 0 success.

Comment: Your reference helped me to some extent then, I am also stuck at the same point as you.

Comment: did you find a solution yet?